# Setting Horizontal Line (NSBox) line width in Interface Builder

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, nsbox

I have an application that I am building am making use of Horizontal Line (which is just a special case of `NSBox`). I've placed the component into the interface, but what to adjust the thickness of the line.

`NSBox` has a `setBorderWidth` method, but doesn't seem to have this exposed when in Interface Builder. I would prefer not to do this manually, as I don't want to have to maintain an object simply to adjust this single value.

Is there a way to set this via Interface Builder that I am just missing?

Or, failing that, is there a better way to put a Horizontal Line in your UI such that you can control it's attributes via Interface Builder?

Answer (score 0):

On the Attributes pane of the inspector, set the Border Type to Custom. Then on the Size pane, set the border width as needed.

Comment: The Attributes panel does not have a Border Type. When you select "Horizontal Line" it doesn't give as much information as a regular NSBox.

Comment: Ah, I see. I misread your intro paragraph. Apologies for the noise.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to instead add a *Custom Box* control (which is an `NSBox`), set its box type to *Custom* and its border type to *Line*.

Then set the control's height to 1 in the normal way, as well as its tint and whatever else you need.

The *Horizontal Line* control is really just a shortcut to get a `NSBox` that's been hard-coded to use the default separator line style; it doesn't allow you to configure much else. But, despite the name, it's neither the only nor arguably the best way to make a horizontal line.